# Why is WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I've highlighted the line in the code that isn't working.  S appears to be a well-defined array populated with numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Function Payouts(StartValue, Vol, CholDecomp)

Dim TrialCounter As Integer
Dim TickerCounter As Integer
Dim BetCounter As Integer
Dim Results As Variant
ReDim Results(1 To 14, 1 To 6) As Double
Dim ZUncorr As Variant
ReDim ZUncorr(1 To 14) As Double
Dim ZCorr As Variant
ReDim ZCorr(1 To 14) As Double
Dim S As Variant
ReDim S(1 To 14) As Double
Dim Ranking As Variant
ReDim Ranking(1 To 14) As Double



For TrialCounter = 1 To 1
    For TickerCounter = 1 To 14
        ZUncorr(TickerCounter) = WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd)
    Next TickerCounter
    ZCorr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.MMult(CholDecomp, WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ZUncorr)))
    For TickerCounter = 1 To 14
        S(TickerCounter) = StartValue(TickerCounter) * Exp(ZCorr(TickerCounter) * Vol(TickerCounter) - Vol(TickerCounter) ^ 2 / 2)
    Next TickerCounter
    For TickerCounter = 1 To 14
        ' error is on next line
        Ranking(TickerCounter) = WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq(S(TickerCounter), S)
    Next TickerCounter
    
Next TrialCounter

Payouts = S

End Function
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Program crash? wrong result? error message (and, if so, what is the error)?  Something else?

Comment: The function produces a #VALUE! error message.

I'm watching the relevant expressions and when the program gets to the offending line it says <Object required> for the value of WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq(S(TickerCounter), S)